# ASP.NET web app is using two versions of the VB compiler - how is this happening?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I used string interpolation in a couple places - once in a VB class, and another in  an aspx page. The VB class runs just fine, but if I try to run the aspx page I get a "character not expected" error on the `$` symbol which denotes an interpolated string. How is this happening? Is there any way I can tell VB to use the newer version of the compiler all the time?

Comment: The interpolated string is in code behind, yes?

Comment: This web app, oddly enough, doesn't have much in the way of code behind; most of the code is in the aspx pages themselves in `<script>` tags.